# Sagging shower door with pivot point away from the wall

Tags: bathroom, repair, shower

As you can see, the pivot point for my door is away from the wall. From what I can see on the top there is simply a hole where there is a pin-like securing mechanism. I cannot tell how the door is attached at the bottom.

Everything I've found online has details on how to repair this problem has the hinge at the wall.

Any guidance would be appreciated, I would obviously like to be able to fix it myself but really unsure where to start.

Thank you :)

<sub>Click to Enlarge</sub>
[image: Top half of door] [image: Top-down view]

[image: Top of the door from another angle] [image: Top pivot point 1]

[image: Top pivot point 2] [image: Bottom pivot point 1]

[image: Bottom pivot point 2] [image: Bottom pivot point 3]

Comment: removing the top frame (the horizontal part) will expose the mechanism so you can fix it

Answer (score 1):

Take the top bar out - 2 hex nuts by the looks of it

[image]

The door will then lift out of the frame, leaving you clear to replace or shim the hinges, or let you decide whether the frame is worn or distorted & itself needs replacement parts.

The top section looks to be pulled outward, which may be contributing.

[image]